# Battery life issues on Xperia Z1 after Lollipop update

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, battery-life, sony-xperia

Since the update of my Xperia Z1 to Lollipop (5.0.2), my battery life is horrible! It takes a very long time to charge it to 100%, and I can only use my phone for a few hours.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the **Battery usage** under **Power Management** in Settings. There you see list of apps showing how much power they have consumed up to then. Check which app is using more battery and uninstall it. If the app is a **System app** (like Android OS, Android SDK, etc) then you need to **Factory Reset** the phone to resolve such issues or if any H/W like **Screen, WiFi, GPS, Radio etc** are using much power then you may consider complaining about the issue in any service center.

Comment: Seems to be the standby. (Screen 17%, Standby 11% !!, OS 10%).

Comment: I would recommend a Factory reset if the issue is persistent. It must solve the problem.